# Looking for a code to build a competitive standing

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking to create a vba-excel based file which recieve games results on one sheet from the end user, and generates a real-time updated standing on the 2nd sheet, based on some rules.
The league is an amateur ping-pong game at work :-) including 14 players, each plays 26 games (home & away structure).
The table need to consider that each win receive 1 point, and sorting should include the difference between positive & negative points.
Any ideas how to create? Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are a lot of excel files similar as the one you want. Google it!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using VLookups, but why reinvent the wheel? These examples do what you need: http://excel-example.com/templates/sport-tournament-template

Comment: Thank you very much! appreciated! :-)

Comment: No problem. If you think it's the correct answer could you mark it as the answer? Thanks.